# How to change text color in QGIS 3 composer label when render as HTML

Tags: qgis-3, print-composer, html, text

I try to set a label with black background, a first line of text in green (exactly rgb(125,185,0) ) and the other line in white.

In QGIS 2.18 setting the background black, the font color white and using HTML tag on the first line `<Font color = rgb(125,185,0)>` worked.

On QGIS 3.6 the first line color change but to a kind of blue (see picture) and trying other RGB combination produce color that doesn't follow any RBG code, it seem that the color tag has an effect but that QGIS doesn't use RGB to render it (in QGIS color selector the rgb(125,185,0) produce the expected green).

Is that a QGIS 3 bug or are my setting wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, it was just missing space before the numerical value

`<Font color = rgb(125,185,0)>` didn't work

but

`<Font color = rgb( 125, 185, 0 )>` work....