# Multi-labelling with different colors in QGIS 3.10

Tags: labeling, symbology, color, qgis-3

I would like to create a multi-field label based on an expression where the different fields will have different colors. 
Using an icon font, this will allow me to get this kind of result (done with ArcGIS):

[image]

I tried using similar expressions in QGIS, changing format to get it "QGIS compatible", but it doesn't work (ArcGIS code: `<CLR red='130' green='130' blue='130'> & [RURAL] & [URBAN] & [CAMP] & </CLR>`.

It seems it was not possible [in previous version](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242864/multi-labeling-with-multiple-colours-in-qgis), I just tried with 3.10... but still the same.

However it's possible in the [print composer to use html tags](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/320696/how-to-change-text-color-in-qgis-3-composer-label-when-render-as-html) to define colors. So am I missing something to make it work on data label also ?

Comment: did you see something in the change log to suggest it would be possible? if not this is just a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242864/multi-labeling-with-multiple-colours-in-qgis

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check the log. I just went through it and nothing about it so I guess it's still not possible.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to change the colour of your icon (or font marker symbol) in Qgis (also with versions elder then 3.10).

Go to Symbology > create your "font marker" symbol and in the option *Colour* click in the
right icon to add a variable > select edit and add the following expression

```
case 
when "field"  =  'no'  then '255,13,1' -- RGB red
when "field"  = 'ok'  then '255, 141, 1' -- RGB green
when "field"  =  'maybe'  then '51, 160, 74' -- RGB orange
else '0,0,0' -- RGB black for no data
  end
```

In the example, "field" is your field with the data that define the colour.

[image: t]

To have more than one font/icon in your label just add (clicking in the green +) a second font marker and repeat the colour operation (changing the "field" ad preferred). Correct the offset of the new symbol to avoid overlaps.

[image]

Comment: Very well done.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it's not completely answering my needs as sometimes one filed will be empty, so using sumbology there will be a hole between symbols.
That's why using labels would be the best solution. Building a concatenate expression between fields and then applying different colors to each field.
I tried using your expression in the label color options but it doesn't work.
It's seems it's not possible.

Comment: I will try to work on it today. The expression should works with few arrangements.

Comment: If I got properly your request, you want to create a multilabel with a lot of variables, one for each field multiplied for all the possible attributes of each of them. Do you have already this expression? Because change the colour of the label is not a problem but you need to refer to the main expression.