# Setting transparency color in Expression Builder

Tags: qgis, expression, color, transparency-opacity

Using QGIS 3.16, I am trying to set color through expression builder, using `#RRGGBBAA` format.

The problem, I was using the same color, let's say `'#94AFDCff'`, it should return the same color as `'#94AFDC'` in `#RRGGBB` format, yet the color that is rendered is fully different. I cannot seem to find out why.
Could anyone help?

The code is simple, it is used in symbol, as a condition of fill colors of circles.

```sql
CASE
    WHEN   "Cat_Num" = 1 THEN '#94AFDC66'
    WHEN  "Cat_Num"  = 2 THEN '#FFFF0066'
    WHEN  "Cat_Num"  =  3 THEN '#ffc40366'
    WHEN  "Cat_Num"  =  4 THEN '#54823566'
    WHEN  "Cat_Num"  =  5 THEN '#7030a066'
    WHEN  "Cat_Num"  =  6 THEN '#843c0c66'
    WHEN  "Cat_Num"  =  7 THEN '#38c0f666'
    WHEN  "Cat_Num"  =  8 THEN '#CCCC0066'
    WHEN  "Cat_Num"  =  9 THEN '#C55A1166'
    WHEN  "Cat_Num"  =  10 THEN '#8d5a9966'
    ELSE 'pink'
END
```

but this code resulted in (notice that the 2 circles are `"Cat_Num" = 8 THEN '#CCCC0066'` and `"Cat_Num" = 10 THEN '#8d5a9966'`)

[image: result picture]

In the end, I did change the code to rgba format, so that `"Cat_Num" = 8 THEN '204, 204, 0, 90'` and `"Cat_Num" = 10 THEN '141, 90, 153, 90'`
with this result:

[image: result]

How are these 2 so different?? The hex color returns pink result for `"Cat_Num" = 8 THEN '#CCCC0066'` (the bigger circle). The smaller circle, which should return purplish, became greenish... Did I make a mistake?

As a reference, in QGIS' own color picker, inputting `'#CCCC0066'`  will have the same color as `'141, 90, 153, 90'`, only different transparency value (90 is about 0.65% for `RRGGBBAA` and 66 in hex is 40% )

[image: Color Picker]

Comment: Please provide both your expression, as well as a screenshot. Thanks.

Comment: Already did, thanks.

Comment: I had a somewhat similar color issue : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/320696/how-to-change-text-color-in-qgis-3-composer-label-when-render-as-html , maybe just double check that all your expression are exactly right...

Comment: I tried, but no difference. I mean, #RRGGBBAA format shouldn't have space in between. And #RRGGBB format returns the right colour. So the problem is the AA behind.. but it should be a hex number, as both format are hex codes anyways. ff should be 255 (which means 100%/opaque) and 00 should be fully transparent, hence the 66 should return 102, which is 0.4 of 255. 

But, this changes the colour. In my case `'#CCCC0066'` returns a completely different colour than `'#CCCC00'`